# __soapCall return the authorization error

Tags: soap-client

I am trying to work upon a soap request and it is returning me the auth failure. So, I tested the SOAP request in SOAP UI tool and found that it gives the expected output. I am doing something wrong in my coding.

```
/*create headers*/
$param= new  SoapVar(array('Authorization' => $username,'password'=>$password), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT); 
$header = new SoapHeader('ns1', 'Authorization', $param,false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

**Make a call**

```
try{    $id=$client->__soapCall('methodname',array('filename'=>$filename,'contents'=>base64_encode($content));
    echo "Received a id:".$id;
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
    var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
}
catch(SoapFault $e){
        echo "Exception\n";
        var_dump($e);
}
```

**The request header as follow**

```
string(207) "POST /services/refresh HTTP/1.1
Host: cpanel.myproject.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.2.11
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 1410
```

In SOAP UI the Headers I notice there is following line as well

Thu Oct 20 13:41:37 IST 2011:DEBUG:>> **"Authorization: Basic XXXX [\r][\n]"**

I am just trying to add this header inside my soapCall any idea how can I do this...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of call with header :

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$httpsheader = new myHeader();
$header = $httpsheader->getHeader();

try 
{
    parent::__construct($wsdl, $header);
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $this->_handleError($e);
}


class myHeader
{   

    function myHeader()
    {

            $this->header = array(
                'proxy_host' => $proxy_host, 
                'proxy_port' => (int)$proxy_port, 
                'proxy_login' => $proxy_login, 
                'proxy_password' => $proxy_pass, 
                'login' => $merchantID,
                'password' => $accessKey,
                'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                'trace' => 1,
                'use' => SOAP_LITERAL);

    }

    function getHeader()
    {
        return $this->header;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can make the successful SoapClient with credentials but in consecutive call _soapCall for method show me the error. I tried giving $input_headers parameter in soapCall method but still I get the error only. ..